# Error on finding OGRE 1.12.4 on Ubuntu with CMake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, ogre, ogre3d

I am getting the following error with CMake when finding the CMake package for OGRE:

```
-- Found OGRE CMake module in directory: /usr/share/OGRE/cmake/modules
CMake Error at /usr/share/OGRE/cmake/modules/OgreTargets.cmake:168 (message):
  The imported target "OgreGLSupport" references the file

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreGLSupport.a"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/share/OGRE/cmake/modules/OgreTargets.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.
```

My filesystem contains the following OGRE libraries:

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgre
libOgreBites.so                    libOgreMain.so                     libOgreOverlay.so                  libOgreProperty.so                 libOgreTerrain.so
libOgreBites.so.1.12.4             libOgreMain.so.1.12.4              libOgreOverlay.so.1.12.4           libOgreProperty.so.1.12.4          libOgreTerrain.so.1.12.4
libOgreHLMS.so                     libOgreMeshLodGenerator.so         libOgrePaging.so                   libOgreRTShaderSystem.so           libOgreVolume.so
libOgreHLMS.so.1.12.4              libOgreMeshLodGenerator.so.1.12.4  libOgrePaging.so.1.12.4            libOgreRTShaderSystem.so.1.12.4    libOgreVolume.so.1.12.4
```

Why does it require the static library?

This is my CMake code:

```
# NOTE search for OGRE before searching for KDE since KDE changes the variable CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
# OGRE does not install the CMake file into the module path. It uses the library path instead.
find_path(OGRE_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR FindOGRE.cmake PATHS ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
message(STATUS "Searching for OGRE in ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

if (NOT OGRE_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR)
    find_path(OGRE_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR FindOGRE.cmake PATHS ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH} PATH_SUFFIXES OGRE/cmake)
endif ()

if (OGRE_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR)
    message(STATUS "Found OGRE CMake module in directory: ${OGRE_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR}")
    set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${OGRE_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR})
else ()
    message(WARNING "Did not find OGRE CMake module.")
endif ()

find_package(OGRE REQUIRED)

# https://ogrecave.github.io/ogre/api/1.10/setup.html
# the search paths
#include_directories(${OGRE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#link_directories(${OGRE_LIBRARY_DIRS})
# copy essential config files next to our binary where OGRE autodiscovers them
#file(COPY ${OGRE_CONFIG_DIR}/plugins.cfg ${OGRE_CONFIG_DIR}/resources.cfg
     #DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

if (${OGRE_FOUND})
    # SYSTEM suppresses all the warnings of OGRE
    include_directories(SYSTEM ${OGRE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${OGRE_LIBRARY_DIRS})

    add_definitions(-DHAS_OGRE=1)
endif ()
```

Comment: Note that CMake doesn't find the library `OgreGLSupport`, which indeed doesn't exist in your library directory. What does your `CMakeLists.txt` file look like, what *exactly* are you searching for? Also have you made sure that you have a full install of the Ogre development libraries (e,g. `libogre-1.12-dev` (or similar), with the `-dev` suffix)?

Comment: Yes I have installed it with the -dev suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I might have messed something up when packaging this and Ubuntu makes it quite hard to fix things once a release (20.04 I assume in your case) has happened.

Please find Ogre 1.12.13 for Ubuntu Focal (20.04) and Ubuntu Jammy (22.04) in my ppa: [https://launchpad.net/~s-schmeisser/+archive/ubuntu/ogre-1.12](https://launchpad.net/%7Es-schmeisser/+archive/ubuntu/ogre-1.12)